# Change structure of serialized object in Django Rest Framework (pull ID field outside of model content)

Tags: json, serialization, django-rest-framework

Say, you have a model with name and e-mail and used Model Serializer to serialize your data with Django Rest Framework. The output would be something like this:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Alex",
    "email": "alex@host.com"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Henry",
    "email": "henry@host.com"
}]
```

Is there a way to "pull" a unique field outside the rest of the model content to get this?:

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "Alex",
        "email": "alex@host.com"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Henry",
        "email": "henry@host.com"
    }
}
```

I am able to "externalize" the ID by overriding serializer's `to_representation()` method (code sample below) but I can't get rid of the rudimental wrappers - currently JRF will return everything as `list[]` of `dict(instance)` similar to this:

```
data = list
for item in instance:
    list.append(item.as_dict())
```

I don't need this to be a `list` of `dicts`, I want them to do be dict of dict?

```
data = {}
for item in instance:
    data[item.id] = item.as_dict()
```

here's my to_representation() code, I can only manipulate what's returned for individual instance, so it has to be a dict, but I need this dict to be merged, rather than stacked at the output when serializer.data is fully cooked.

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = OrderedDict()
    fields = self._readable_fields
    id_field = filter(lambda i: i.label == "ID", fields)[0]
    if id_field:
        id_atr = id_field.get_attribute(instance).__str__()
    else:
        raise Exception('cannot serialize models without ID field')
    rep[id_atr] = {}
    for field in fields:
        try:
            attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
        except SkipField:
            continue
        if attribute is None:
            rep[id_atr][field.field_name] = None
        else:
            rep[id_atr][field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
    return rep
```

I was able to make it work by reformatting the original serializer output, but it's surely not a clean solution with a lot of performance impact:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    _data = super(ChatMessageViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    _resp = {}
    for item in _data.data:
        _id = item.get('id', None)
        if not _id:
            raise Exception('cannot serialize data without id field')
        _resp[_id] = {}
        for element in item:
            _resp[_id][element] = item[element]
    _data.data = _resp
    return _data
```

as per @zaphod100-10 answer, I have created a custom ListSerializer class:

```
class ChatMessageListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):

        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        _data = {}
        for item in iterable:
            _data[item.id] = self.child.to_representation(item)
        return _data
```

and it formats the data the way I need this:
[image: debug view screenshot]

but my data does not survive 'ListModelMixin':

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

it returns a list[] of just the entity ids: `[1L, 2L, 3L...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom ListSerializer for your model and override the to_representation method.

```
def to_representation(self, data):
    # convert your data which is a queryset or a 
    # list of objects to dict of dicts
    .....
    return dict_of_dicts
```

After creating the ListSerializer in your main serializer class add list_serializer_class meta property.

read more about list serializer here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer

Comment: Interestingly, the data does not survive `ListModelMixin()` I have updated the question to elaborate on the problem.

Comment: check your code again. ListModelMixin does nothing special but gives the data to the serializer class with many=true. Rest is the up to the serializer. Can you paste your current code?

Comment: @zaphod100.00, yeah, but I can't figure where the data gets killed, code here: http://pastebin.com/FVka6s4T

Comment: @abolotnov is pagination on? Paginator will cast your dict to a list which will  make a list of keys. I guess this is what is happening.

Comment: No, no pagination, unless I need to explicitly turn it off

Comment: @abolotnov yes, explicitly turn it off. DRF has default pagination

Comment: set pagination_class in the view to None - hasn't cured it. Must be something else.

Comment: I figured this out, output of of to_representation() must be a list